# Login module in Titanium

Tags: authentication, titanium

Any one has experience in development of Login module with ProviderService.Src.

I need to develop a login module with the webservice using Titanium Appcelerator. It needs to take two strings (Username & Password) and return true/false. I need to send entered login and password via web service and receive true/false. The webservice is

```
http://46.18.8.42/FareBids.Service/FareBids.ServiceLayer.ProviderService.svc
```

Please some one guide me how to create a Login module with it? I got information which says me to use SUDS. Can some one help me on this with code(if possible)
 Help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a webservice http client. This should do it, you will have to tune this to your specific webservice and obviously collect data from the user, but how to do that is well documented in [the most basic Titanium tutorials.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/User_Interface_Fundamentals)

```
    var loginSrv = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function(e) {
             // If the service returns successfully : true, or false
             var isUserAllowed = this.responseText; 
        },
        onerror : function(e) {
            // Web service failed for some reason
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            Ti.API.info('webservice failed with message : ' + e.error);
        }
    });
    loginSrv.open('POST', 'http://46.18.8.42/FareBids.Service/FareBids.ServiceLayer.ProviderService.svc');
    // you may have to change the content type depending on your service
    loginSrv.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    var sendObj = {loginid : 'someid', pwd : 'somepassword'};
    loginSrv.send(obj);
```

Comment: Please look at the webservice link. I dont have any DB there... Just using this url, please tell me how to go with the login module. I got some information that using suds.js we can proceed. But not sure how to do it. If anyone was successful with this, Please give me the code. Thanks.

Comment: Also when I tried with the code that is here, it says [INFO][TiAPI   (  688)] webservice failed with message : Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. Please help me on this about the content type. Thanks.